# Could anyone give me some hint on how to do this one?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, linear-transformations

I know that Ax=b is just a translation of the Homogeneous solution Ax=0. But since A is not given, how do I give all solutions?

[image]

Comment: Is it possible that this problem has a part (a) that isn't being shown?

Comment: Thanks, @Austin C, I was so careless that I didn't notice. Thanks you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

If $Ax=b$ then $Ay=b\iff A(y-x)=0\iff y-x\in \{z: Az=0\}\iff y\in \{x+z: Az=0\}.$